# Rails route appears in routes but throws a 404

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, routes, ruby-on-rails-5

I'm trying to add a simple route to an existing controller/action but strangely I'm getting a 404 error even though the route appears to exist.

Here's the relevant section of my `routes.rb`:

```
  # Wines
  scope 'wine' do
    get '/',                  to: 'wines#index',              as: 'wine_index'
    get '/:collection',       to: 'wines#collection_detail',  as: 'collection_detail'
    get '/:collection/:slug', to: 'wines#wine_detail',        as: 'wine_detail'
    get '/:style',            to: 'wines#style_detail',       as: 'style_detail'
  end
```

It seems correct because here's what I see when I check:

```
$ rake routes
=>

            Prefix Verb     URI Pattern                                              Controller#Action

        wine_index GET      /wine(.:format)                                          wines#index
 collection_detail GET      /wine/:collection(.:format)                              wines#collection_detail
       wine_detail GET      /wine/:collection/:slug(.:format)                        wines#wine_detail
      style_detail GET      /wine/:style(.:format)                                   wines#style_detail

                   GET|POST /*path(.:format)                                         pages#error404
```

I also see an expected response in the console:

```
2.3.1 :003 > app.style_detail_path('semi-dry')
 => "/wine/semi-dry"
```

Yet, when I try to visit `/wine/semi-sweet/` (Semi-sweet is a style "slug" which I use to search in the action) I get a 404 error.

What could I me missing? I've searched dozens of similar questions on S.O. and none of the solutions apply to my situation.

Comment: What happens if you remove the trailing slash?

Comment: @jvillian No change. Still 404

Comment: Pls post the error from your terminal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems you need to specify constraints. When you say 'wines/semi-sweet', how would the router decide whether it's a style_detail path or a colletion_detail path?  They both have the same mask '/wines/:something'

It should be something like:

```
scope 'wine' do
    get '/',                  to: 'wines#index',              as: 'wine_index'
    get '/:style',            to: 'wines#style_detail',       as: 'style_detail', constraints: proc { |r| Style.include?(r.params[:style]) }
    get '/:collection',       to: 'wines#collection_detail',  as: 'collection_detail'
    get '/:collection/:slug', to: 'wines#wine_detail',        as: 'wine_detail'
  end
```

This way the router will match predefined words (could be an array too) with wine styles, all the other strings will be considered as wine collections.

But it would be best to change the mask for these two paths, just to be safe, for example:

```
   get '/:style',            to: 'wines#style_detail',       as: 'style_detail'
   get '/c/:collection',       to: 'wines#collection_detail',  as: 'collection_detail'
```

Comment: Yup. I was just starting to notice this. I wonder why Rails doesn't warn me about it the way that it does when you try to create a duplicate path_name.

Comment: The router is throwing a 404 because you have a collection path first, so it searches for a collection named 'semi-dry', which does not exist.

But simply reordering routes won't help, you need to specify constraints or change the "mask"

Comment: Right. I get it. I'm just curious why `rake routes` will throw a helpful error if you try to name two routes the same thing (Ex: `wine_detail` and `wine_detail`) but it didn't complain at all about my conflicting routes (Ex: `/wine/:something` and `/wine/:something-else` which are effectively the exact same thing)

Comment: If the client wants the URLs to be the same, do you see a problem with simply adding a constraint to both routes so Rails knows which is which?

Comment: Oops... When I write a constraint like yours I get `TypeError (wrong argument type String (expected Module)): config/routes.rb:53:in `include?'` Should this work on Rails 5?

Comment: You could add a constraint to the path that has fewer possible variations, style in this case (there are like 5 of them, right?)

And all the other strings will be routed to collections, so you don't need a constraint on this one. But generally it's not a good idea to have routes that look the same.

In this case two constraints would be overkill

Comment: You should adapt the code to your specific app. Maybe use an array if there is no Style model in your app

 %w( sweet dry semisweet ).include?(r.params[:style])

Comment: The error is from the `r.params[:style]` not the model name. It appears that in Rails (5) `include?()` doesn't expect a string.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/134119/discussion-between-dmitry-kukhlevsky-and-emersonthis).

Comment: Here is what worked for me: `constraints: lambda { |r| !Style.where(slug: r.params[:style]).empty?`