# Resource routes exists but Rails throws a 404

Tags: ruby-on-rails, url-routing, ruby-on-rails-5

This is NOT a duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41881523/rails-route-appears-in-routes-but-throws-a-404), since I'm not using custom routes for this resource, nor slugs. I'm using Rails 5.

This is my router

```
namespace :api, defaults: { format: :json } do
      namespace :v1 do
        resources :node_categories, only: [:create, :update, :destroy]
        resources :edge_categories, only: [:create, :update, :destroy]
        resources :nodes, only: [:index, :create, :destroy] do
          collection do
            match '/bulk' => 'nodes#bulk', via: :post
          end
        end
```

Everything seems fine. `rake routes` prints the routes OK

```
api_v1_node_categories POST   /api/v1/node_categories(.:format)     api/v1/node_categories#create {:format=>:json}
  api_v1_node_category PATCH  /api/v1/node_categories/:id(.:format) api/v1/node_categories#update {:format=>:json}
                       PUT    /api/v1/node_categories/:id(.:format) api/v1/node_categories#update {:format=>:json}
                       DELETE /api/v1/node_categories/:id(.:format)
```

The controllers are well namespaced and the tests are passing (not doing route tests in this project though). All other routes seem to work fine. Only this resource is giving troubles. Any request to any action returns 404 but the **log shows no** such requests, no errors nor exceptions, not nothing.

All client application, Postman and even curl behave the same way, a phantom 404 is returned, along with an empty response, with no record of it in the logs.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Test

```
scope '/api' do
    scope '/v1' do
       ...
    end
end
```

Instead of namespace, I use that in my APIs.

Answer (score 0):

The error turned out to be related to Fabio's (my router) route permissions. The new routes needed to be allowed.

It had nothing to do with Rails.